# Debug PHP with Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

What is the best way to debug PHP with Eclipse? Specifically, I'm trying to work through some issues on a Drupal 6 installation.

I like Eclipse's debugging for Java. Is there a way to do the same for PHP?

Answer (score 19):

I've never used Eclipse to develop in JAVA, but if you are asking about a graphical debugger that allows to set up breakpoints, go through the current stack trace, see content of variables, and all that, there is (at least one) a solution:

You can use the [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension, and [**Eclipse PDT**](http://eclipse.org/pdt/) as IDE : the second one is able to use the first one as debugger, and provides an interface for it -- kind of what you might expect if you have used a visual debugger in other languages/IDE.

I've used this combination a couple of times with Drupal, to see what was executed, in which order, how, and all that *(not easy to get "by hand", with the hooks mecanism)*, and it definitly works pretty well.

There are tutorials available on the net that explain how to setup both of those to get the debugger working. For instance :

- [How To Setup a Free PHP Debugger using Eclipse PDT + XDebug](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug)
- [Setting up Eclipse to Debug Drupal with XDebug](http://echodittolabs.org/drupal-xdebug-pdt-eclipse) *(unfortunatly, the screenshots are missing)*
- Or (in french, but with screenshots ; so, might be helpful evn if not easy to understand) :

  - [Débugger avec WampServer, Xdebug et PDT](http://blog.wampserver.com/index.php/2009/08/28/debugger-avec-wampserver-xdebug-et-pdt/)
  - [Configurer Xdebug pour Eclipse PDT en utilisant un serveur de test distant](http://blog.christophelebot.fr/2008/11/02/configurer-xdebug-eclipse-pdt-serveur-test-distant/)

And here is a screenshot of what it can look like *(here, I've set a breakpoint somewhere is the backoffice of Dotclear)* :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/eclipse-xdebug-debug-1.png))</sub>

*(In theory, clicking on the image should get you to a bigger version)*

The icons on top of the windows will allow you to do stuff like :

- step by step
- step in / out of functions / methods

And you can also

- see the content of variables *(top right of the screenshot)*
- have a stack trace showing where you are *(top left of the screen shot)*
- of course, see were you are in the code *(bottom)*

I've also heard that Eclipse PDT can use the Zend Debugger extension instead of Xdebug ; but I've never tried this one.

Answer (score 2):

You Can add this code in php.in file for enabling debugger.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\opt\lampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using the PDT for whatever reason, you could use CodeMix as a lightweight alternative to debug PHP in Eclipse. You still would need XDebug installed, of course - see [this doc](https://www.genuitec.com/docs/web-apps/modern-web/getting-started-with-php-in-eclipse/#Debugging) for more details.