# How to debug in eclipse for php code?

Tags: php, eclipse

I am new developer in php and i am using eclipse with php. In that how to debug php code in eclipse? Let me help how debug breakpoints in eclipse?

In advance thanking to help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug PHP with Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582897/debug-php-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is very similar to ZendStudio (which is eclipse also).

Just place a breakpoint at desired line, create running configuration (as CLI/CGI or Web page) and press run.

This PDF may answer all questions for you : http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf