# Debugging php code using breakpoints on eclipse

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I am new to php and running php on my system .

As IDE I am using
Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Helios

As server I am using : WAMPSERVER

Basically on eclipse I link my php project to one I have placed in www folder of wamp installation. I do all development in eclipse and then run the project on wampserver.

What I am not able to do is debug the code at all. I want to use breakpoints debugging as I could in Java programming using eclipse.

Please help, I have seen so many threads about xdebug and zend debug, but these have been of no help to me,

Any help is appreciated, let me know if I am doing everything wrong as in using both eclispse and wamp separately.

Thanks

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582897/debug-php-with-eclipse

Comment: Thanks Saber, I found a more simple version , still thanks much.     http://www.softhem.se/blog/how-to-setup-php-debugging-in-eclipse-xdebug